# Windows service installation error

Tags: c#, .net, service, publishing

I was getting below mentioned error whenever i tried to publish this windows service

> Error 116 "obj\Debug\WindowsService.csproj.WindowsService.exe.config;obj\Debug\WindowsDateService.exe.config"
>   is an invalid value for the "ConfigFile" parameter of the
>   "GenerateApplicationManifest" task. Multiple items cannot be passed
>   into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".

So I commented out itemgroup node shown below in .csproj file

```
<TransformXml Source="App.config" Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config" Transform="App.$(Configuration).config" />
    <!--Force build process to use the transformed configuration file from now on.-->
    <ItemGroup>
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="App.config" />
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config">
        <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
      </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

So i got rid of the error mentioned above and i was able to publish the windows service in a folder.. Now when i try to run setup.exe file i get an error. Error details are mentioned below.

> at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyFileHash(String
>   filePath, Hash hash)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyFileHash(String
>   filePath, HashCollection hashCollection)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyComponents()
>             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState
>   subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest
>   appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group,
>   IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState
>   subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId,
>   TempDirectory& downloadTemp)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState&
>   subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri
>   activation

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 or higher?

Try to change:

```
<AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="app.config" />
```

To:

```
<AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="@(AppConfigWithTargetPath)"/>
```

I had the same error and this post helped me: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/183829/view.html